# Cauchy formula for polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with this problem, any help appreciated. It says:

"If $P(z)$ is a polynomial, prove that

$\int_{|z-a|=r}{P(z)d\bar{z}} = -2\pi i r^2 P'(a)$.

So far I'm using that $P'(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-a|=r}{\frac{P(z)}{(z-a)^2}dz}$ (which is what I get when differentiating on Cauchy's formula) but I'm not sure how to get the $d\bar{z}$. I also see that in order to get the equality asked I should make the change of variables $z-a=r$ right?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|z-a|=r \implies (z-a)(\bar{z}-\bar{a}) = r^2 \implies \bar{z}-\bar{a} = \frac{r^2}{z-a} \implies d\bar{z} = -r^2 \frac{dz}{(z-a)^2} $$

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for your help.
One thing I'm noticing: where am I using the fact that P is a polynomial? So far I can do this with any complex function, as long as it is holomorphic, right?

Comment: @BouvetIsland: holomorphic within the given disk, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Parametrize:

$$z=a+re^{it}\;,\;\;0\le t\le2\pi\implies \overline z=a+re^{-it}\implies d\overline z=-ire^{-it}dt\implies$$

$$I:=\oint\limits_{|z-a|=r}P(z)d\overline z=-ir\int\limits_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}P\left(a+re^{it}\right)dt$$

and we do integration by parts:

$$\begin{align*}u&=P(a+re^{it})\;\;&,\;\;u'&=ire^{it}P'(a+re^{it})\\
v'&=e^{-it}\;\;&,\;\;v&=ie^{-it}\end{align*}$$

so

$$I=\underbrace{\left.re^{-it}P(a+re^{it})\right|_0^{2\pi}}_{=0}-ir^2\int\limits_0^{2\pi}P'(a+re^{it})dt\stackrel{**}=$$

$$\stackrel{**}=-2\pi ir^2 P'(a)$$

** This is [Gauss' Mean Value](http://planetmath.org/gaussmeanvaluetheorem)